# how can I add auto layout constraints for a line programatically

Tags: swift3, constraints, xcode8, ios-autolayout

I drew a line programatically in y `UI`. How can I add constraints for this line.

```
let line = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 10, y: 350, width: 350, height: 1))
line.backgroundColor = UIColor.white;self.view.addSubview(line)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I created a red line: **height = 1, top = 50 and the width will be flexible** You can modify the position as you want.

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)

    let line = UIView()
    line.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
    view.addSubview(line)

    line.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

    let leadingConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: line, attribute: .left, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: view, attribute: .left, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 20.0)
    let topConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: line, attribute: .top, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: view, attribute: .top, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 50.0)
    let trailingConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: view, attribute: .right, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: line, attribute: .right, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 20.0)
    let heightConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: line, attribute: .height, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: nil, attribute: .notAnAttribute, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 1.0)

    view.addConstraints([topConstraint, leadingConstraint, trailingConstraint, heightConstraint])
}
```

The result!

[image]

Comment: Sorry mate.I am just getting a white screen when i tried your code.Why is it not coming for me.

Comment: Let copy my code and paste in **viewDidAppear** method. Is it working?

Comment: Or you set the line's color to white?

Comment: no. i just copy paste your code exactly as it is.still i am not getting it

Comment: Let create a new project and try with my code. Will be it working?

Comment: @faheem Constraints are right and they are properly working.

Comment: thank you so much bro..thats working fine now. thanks for the help.@DanhHuynh

Answer (score 1):

**NSLayoutConstraint Style**

```
NSLayoutConstraint(item: line, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.CenterX, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: view, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.CenterX, multiplier: 1, constant: 0).active = true
NSLayoutConstraint(item: line, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.CenterY, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: view, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.CenterY, multiplier: 1, constant: 0).active = true`
```

Comment: Thanks for a quick response. But this is not making any changes to the line. if i change the model in simulator, the line is not appearing in the same place.@tabassum